# Change duplicate handling of records

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

How can defaults of `First Name` and `Last Name` from Leads module duplicate handling "fields to be matched on" can be replaced with custom fields?

I need to overwrite that default behavior so some records can be merged when my custom criteria matches

Comment: Please, make a summary in the title and in the body of the question give a background of what are you trying to achieve & provide your code

Comment: Thanks for the reply Acrones. what i am trying to achieve is that in Vtigercrm 7 open source. I need to change duplicate handling of records so that records can be merged when criteria matches. The default fields for duplicate matching are First Name and Last Name. which i need to change to a custom field in Leads Module. How can this be achieved?